# Core Bluetooth not asking authentication pin while pairing?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I tried to connect the iPhone device using core Bluetooth, it is not asking the pin while pairing why?

```
self.centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey : value])
```

It is calling the did Connect delegate method. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: Do any of your characteristics require encryption?  If not then bonding doesn’t happen

Comment: @Paul yes encryption is required for characteristics

Comment: Then you will get a pairing dialogue when you try and read or write one of those chracteristics.

Comment: At the time of connection, it will show pairing dialogue or when we access characteristic.

Comment: When you first access a characteristic that requires encryption. Connection alone isn’t enough

Comment: Can you please refer any blog to understand things better. I went through this https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluetooth-pairing-passkey-entry/ and assuming it will show pairing dialogue at the connection stage.

Comment: I don't know of any blog posts or articles, I just know from experience that iOS won't initiate bonding until the encryption key is required, which happens when you read or write an encrypted characteristic

Comment: Thank you Paul for valuable information.